# Avoiding deletion of SpooledTemporaryFile

Tags: python, file, python-3.4, temporary-files

A [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) from the tempfile module in Python is a temporary file created in the system memory rather than on the disc. However, it can be rolled over to the disc at any point by calling the appropriately named `rollover` method. Once the file is closed, it will be deleted, and that is precisely what I am trying to prevent.

The [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) has a `delete` keyword argument in its constructor that does the job, but the same isn't available for SpooledTemporaryFile. One way to solve this is by making a copy of this file before it is closed. This requires additional `copy` operations, and precautions must be taken to avoid race conditions. It also requires more resources. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: If you ultimately want to keep the file, why not just use the `NamedTemporaryFile(..., delete=False)`? What is your use case?

Comment: @mhawke The fact that files kept in memory can be read/written quickly than their counterpart is why I am preferring it this way. I believe this is one of the major reasons why `SpooledTemporaryFile` exists.

Comment: Maybe use a  memory mapped file? See [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) module.

Comment: @mhawke Thank you. I shall look in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is available at my disposal, I decided to take a look at the source code - [tempfile.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tempfile.py). This is how the chain of events progresses in that module:

- A `SpooledTemporaryFile` is initiated as an `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` object.
- When it is rolled over to the disc, a `TemporaryFile` file object is created, and the IO stream object is abandoned for garbage collection.
- This new file is different for several platforms. On Windows or CygWin systems this new file is a `NamedTemporaryFile`, the close method of which is accessed through a wrapper class called `_TemporaryFileCloser`. We can override some methods and jump through some hoops <sup>*****</sup> to eventually set `delete=False` in order to achieve our goal.
- On posix systems, the new file is just another volatile IO stream *(sigh...)*

***** The workaround is to subclass it and override the `rollover` method. The code below works on both posix and Windows systems. On Windows, you may skip the `rollover` part - only the `__init__` is necessary.

```
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile

class CustomSpooled(SpooledTemporaryFile):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # This dict will be passed on to the NamedTempFile constructor one we
        # roll over our file. We are adding the delete=False argument.
        self._TemporaryFileArgs = {'mode': mode, 'buffering': buffering,
                                   'suffix': suffix, 'prefix': prefix,
                                   'encoding': encoding, 'newline': newline,
                                   'dir': dir, 'delete': False}

    def rollover(self):
        # This is overidden to get that NamedTemperoraryFile
        # Everythng else is just the same
        if self._rolled: return
        file = self._file
        newfile = self._file = NamedTemporaryFile(**self._TemporaryFileArgs)
        del self._TemporaryFileArgs

        newfile.write(file.getvalue())
        newfile.seek(file.tell(), 0)

        self._rolled = True
```

---

> <sup>**CAUTION! This is evidently a dirty hack, therefore I do not recommend this for production code or anything of the sort.**</sup>

Comment: is there a way to prevent the spooledtemporaryfile to be closed when exiting the with statsment ?